# can we change image icon dynamically when on focus in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

A text filed called "XYZ with cancel image icon at the suffix". Cancel image icon initial is in black.
When User focus on text filed cancel image icon should change into green icon.

Note- Black image icon, green image icon are added in asset/images by developer.

Is there any way to get this!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Focus` widget which wraps the `TextField`. Inside `onFocusChange` callback use `setState` to change the state variable which keeps icon color.

Declare state class variable:

```dart
Color _cancelColor = Colors.black;
```

Inside `build` method:

```dart
Focus(
  onFocusChange: (focused) {
    setState(() {
      _cancelColor = focused ?
        Colors.green : Colors.black;
    });
  },
  child: TextField(
    ...
    suffix: Icon(Icons.xxx, color: _cancelColor),
  ),
)
```